# How to find the sum of multiple columns sum in single query

Tags: laravel

Here i want to get the total sum of (sum of SaleQnt + sum of ReturnQnt + sum of WasteQnt).From this query i can find all the sum groupby each product.But can't get the total sum of all individual sum.

```
$return_products = DB::table('ready_products_allocate_return')
                    ->join('ready_product_allocate_return_details','ready_product_allocate_return_details.RtnID','ready_products_allocate_return.id')
                    ->select('ready_product_allocate_return_details.CatID','ready_product_allocate_return_details.ItemID','ready_product_allocate_return_details.ReturnQnt')
                    ->select('ready_product_allocate_return_details.CatID','ready_product_allocate_return_details.ItemID',DB::raw('sum(ready_product_allocate_return_details.SaleQnt) as tSaleQnt'),DB::raw('sum(ready_product_allocate_return_details.ReturnQnt) as tReturnQnt'),DB::raw('sum(ready_product_allocate_return_details.WasteQnt) as tWasteQnt'))
                    ->where('ready_product_allocate_return_details.StoreID',$wrhouseID)
                    ->where('ready_product_allocate_return_details.Date',$selDate)
                    ->groupBy('ready_product_allocate_return_details.ItemID')
                    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can make one select statement like this

```php
$return_products = DB::table('ready_products_allocate_return')
    ->selectRaw(
        'ready_product_allocate_return_details.CatID
        ,ready_product_allocate_return_details.ItemID
        ,ready_product_allocate_return_details.ReturnQnt
        ,ready_product_allocate_return_details.CatID
        ,ready_product_allocate_return_details.ItemID
        ,sum(ready_product_allocate_return_details.SaleQnt) as tSaleQnt
        ,sum(ready_product_allocate_return_details.ReturnQnt) as tReturnQnt
        ,sum(ready_product_allocate_return_details.WasteQnt) as tWasteQnt
        ,(tSaleQnt + tReturnQnt + tWasteQnt) as total'
    )
    ->join('ready_product_allocate_return_details', 'ready_product_allocate_return_details.RtnID', 'ready_products_allocate_return.id')
    ->where([
        'ready_product_allocate_return_details.StoreID' => $wrhouseID,
        'ready_product_allocate_return_details.Date' => $selDate
    ])
    ->groupBy('ready_product_allocate_return_details.ItemID')
    ->get();
```

ref link https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#raw-methods

---

or if you want only sum of `total`

```php
$return_products = DB::table('ready_products_allocate_return')
    ->selectRaw(
        'ready_product_allocate_return_details.CatID
        ,ready_product_allocate_return_details.ItemID
        ,ready_product_allocate_return_details.ReturnQnt
        ,ready_product_allocate_return_details.CatID
        ,ready_product_allocate_return_details.ItemID
        ,(sum(ready_product_allocate_return_details.SaleQnt) + sum(ready_product_allocate_return_details.ReturnQnt) + sum(ready_product_allocate_return_details.WasteQnt)) as total'
    )
    ->join('ready_product_allocate_return_details', 'ready_product_allocate_return_details.RtnID', 'ready_products_allocate_return.id')
    ->where([
        'ready_product_allocate_return_details.StoreID' => $wrhouseID,
        'ready_product_allocate_return_details.Date' => $selDate
    ])
    ->groupBy('ready_product_allocate_return_details.ItemID')
    ->get();
    }
```

Comment: "message": "Type error: Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder::selectRaw() must be of the type array, string given.Brother here get this error in '(tSaleQnt + tReturnQnt + tWasteQnt) as total' line

Comment: @Ohidul opss try now

Comment: ->where([
                    'ready_product_allocate_return_details.StoreID' => $wrhouseID,
                    'ready_product_allocate_return_details.Date','like',$getMonth.'%'
                ]).how to use like condition here?